# af:selectItem disabled property isn't working in IE9/Chrome/Safari

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, jsf, safari, oracle-adf

I'm trying to disabled few options of af:selectOneChoice. I tried the following code

```
<af:selectOneChoice value="#{ticket_bean.class}" 
                    immediate="true" autoSubmit="true" id="travelSlass"
                    valueChangeListener="#{ticket_bean.classChangeEvent}"
                    simple="true" valuePassThru="true" >
    <af:forEach     var="item" items="#{ticket_bean.classList}">
        <af:selectItem value="#{item.value}" label="#{item.classDesc}" 
                       disabled="#{item.notAvailable}"/>
     </af:forEach>
 </af:selectOneChoice>
```

This code is working fine only in firefox. Safari,chrome,IE are not showing the disabled option. Any Workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If oracle-adf doesn't render the html correctly to handle this in all browser, then you can only do that yourself.

One option might be to use css to hide elements using the styleClass attribute (I haven't use oracle-adf, but I assume it has this standard attribute as well.

The probably cleaner, more secure and in general better option would be to remove the select items from `#{ticket_bean.classList}` in the managed bean, before rendering and then not using any disabled attribute at all.